# PHP Output (PDO & CRUD)

Tags: php, crud

I need help with my PHP script.

I have 3 Tables in my Database (its German so sorry if you dont understand ^^):

```
-firma (in english company)
-produkt (in english product)
-firmaprodukt (in english companyproduct)
```

If I click on a company, the product image should be output (from the "Produkt" database) and the appropriate URL (from the "firmaprodukt").

So far I've managed that when you click on a company, the ID is displayed (example: `"localhost/TESTING//index?1="`) but I'm struggling with the output.

That's my index.php script for the output:

```
<div class="col-xl-6">
    <div id="login_content">
        <div class="scrollP">
<?php
$fpresults = $fpCrud->getPicUrl($FirmenID); 
?>
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center heading-div">
                <h3> <?= $result['firmenname']?> </h3>
            </div>

            <table border="0">
                <tbody>
<?php
foreach ($fpresults as $fpresult){
?>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="box customer-box" data-parent="#login_card" id="project_reg_box">
                            <a href="<?= $fpresult['url']?>"> <img src="dashboard/TESTING/<?= $fpresult['ProduktLogo']?>" height="100%" > </a>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
<?php  
} 
?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that's in my crud.php:

```
public function getPicUrl($FirmenID) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->query(
            "SELECT fp.FirmenID, f.firmenname, p.ProduktLogo, fp.url 
            FROM firma f 
                JOIN firmaprodukt fp ON fp.FirmenID = f.FirmenID 
                JOIN produkt p ON fp.ProduktID = p.ProduktID 
            WHERE fp.FirmenID = :FirmenID");

    $stmt->execute(array(':FirmenID' => $FirmenID));
    $data = $stmt->fetch();
    return $data;
}
```

In my `formprocess.php` I don't have anything for that.

Comment: First, enable error reporting by adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the first line in the PHP code block of your `index.php`. Also, you mentioned `formprocess.php`, what is it?

Comment: I actually understand German, but I honestly don't understand what the question shall be? Besides, it's generally a bad practice to use German variable names, because the result will always be Kauderwelsch.

Comment: i enabled the `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and dont get an error.

my formprocess is a php for the logic like 

`if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
                $ProduktID = $_GET['delete'];
  
                $_SESSION['msg-class'] = "success";
                $_SESSION['msg'] = "Deleting worked!";
        
                $ProduktCrud->deleteProdukt($ProduktID);
                header('location: produkt.php');
                exit;
  `

Comment: `/TESTING//index?1=` is definitely not a correct URL - and you're not processing the `$_GET` either. Add static typing to the method signature `int $FirmenID` and it might throw an error.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I would like to know how I can filter the whole thing so that only the product images including the URL are output, and the company ID also fits

Comment: How about `/TESTING/index?id=1` and then `$company_id = (int) $_GET['id']`?

Comment: I'm currently trying the link with a `<a href="dashboard.php?id=<?= $result['FirmenID']; ?>">` but it doesn't work. How would I do that otherwise, with the URL? I also used the `<form class="Get">`

Comment: nvm, did it with the url

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the problem is here as it's not clear. Are you failing to actually display the image and product hyperlink?

Comment: The question's title is also way too broad...

Comment: @Professor Abronsius So far I have had an ID in the URL when I click on a company (`localhost/index.php?id=1` as an example). Now I would like to display the products that the company has (with the appropriate link)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

index.php

```php
<?php
                if (isset($_GET['firmaprodukte'])) {
                    $FirmenID = (int) $_GET['firmaprodukte'];
                    $firmaprodukte = $fpCrud->getPicUrl($_GET['firmaprodukte']);
                    $firmenresults = $firmaCrud->getFirma($_GET['firmaprodukte']);
                ?>
                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                            <div class="scrollP">
                                <div id="login_content">
                                    <div id="login_card" class="container">
                                        <?php
                                             $fpresults = $fpCrud->getPicUrl($FirmenID); 
                                         ?>
                                         <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center heading-div">
                                                 <h3> <?= $firmenresults['firmenname']?> </h3>
                                         </div>

                                         <table border="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                 <?php
                                                 foreach ($fpresults as $fpresult){
                                                 ?>
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <div class="box customer-box" data-parent="#login_card" id="project_reg_box">
                                                         <a href="<?= $fpresult['url']?>"> <img src="dashboard/TESTING/<?= $fpresult['ProduktLogo']?>" height="80vh" max-width="200vh"> </a>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <?php  } ?>
                                             </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Crud.php

```php
        public function getPicUrl($FirmenID) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT fp.FirmenID, f.firmenname, p.ProduktLogo, fp.url FROM firma f JOIN firmaprodukt fp ON fp.FirmenID = f.FirmenID JOIN produkt p ON fp.ProduktID = p.ProduktID WHERE fp.FirmenID = :FirmenID");
            $stmt->execute(array(':FirmenID' => $FirmenID));
            $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
            return $data;
        }
```

formprocess.php

```php
if(isset($_POST['firmaprodukte'])) {

            $FirmenID = $_POST['FirmenID'];


           if($crud->getPicUrl($FirmenID)) {
               header('location: FirmaProdukt.php');
               exit;

           } else{
            header('location: FirmaProdukt.php');
            exit;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).